# Why zip files will be added from the scratch in git?

Tags: git, zip

I have a zip file named `db_dump.zip` on the repository. It has 150MB size. When I make some changes in the db (adding a new column to one of tables) and then make a new dump, and zip it, then the whole 150MB will be uploaded when I run `git push origin master`.

Why? And how can I avoid this? should I use unzip files? Like `db_dump.sql`? *(I've tested it and in this case just changes will be uploaded)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you zipping it? Zip files are binaries, whereas SQL files are text. Git can store changes in text files, but it can't do so for binaries; it doesn't know that zip files should be treated differently to image files or compiled programs.

Don't zip your database dump before putting it in Git.

Comment: You know, that unzipped db_dump has about 500MB .. My internet is poor and pushing will be abort unexpectly .. `:-(`

Comment: See if you can upload it once, then you'll only need to upload the changes each time. Upload it piece by piece if you have to by creating a version with the first 10MB, then the first 20MB...

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer (click on the grey tick to make it green - but you probably know that already).